# What scriptures, other than the Yoga Sutras and the Bhagavad Gita, mention Maitri, Karuna, Mudita and Upeksha?

Tags: scripture, yoga, meditation, yoga-sutras, raja-yoga

I know that these are mentioned in Buddhist scriptures, but I'm specifically interested in their occurrence in Hindu scriptures.

Comment: Just for the contextual reference purpose can please you add those verses from Yoga Sutras and BG to your question which contain the names your have listed?